# ajax request responding empty braces on server side

Tags: node.js

I was trying to send data from client side to server using ajax but for some reason when I log the req.body on server side the ajax is responding empty braces but I assiged a string on the client side. Where did i go wrong why isn't the data assigned on client side logging on server side. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Client Side

```
$.ajax({
    data: 'hello',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
    crossDomain: true,
    done: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Server Side

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/api', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body) //logging empty braces
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port 8000`);
});
```

Comment: You don't specify a content-type with appropriate content format on the client-side.  And, then you don't show any middleware to actually read the body on the server side that knows about that particular content-type.  You have to do both.  Also, your server doesn't send any response back to the client so the request will just "hang" and eventually timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you need to serialize your data on the client side. [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/#serialize) has a serialize method that:

> creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation

I'm not to sure how to handle the server side of things.